# How to get rid of warnings about enabling Core Animation Layer

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, core-animation

I experimented a bit with transitions for my subviews in a Cocoa app I'm developing. After rolling them back I'm left with 5 warnings stating "Unsupported Configuration: Adding a subview transition requires the view or one of its ancestors to enable Core Animation Layer".

How do I get rid of them?

EDIT: To clarify: I just toyed around with the transitions to see how they would work out but then removed them all. Also did a "clean" from the menu and a rebuild of my project.

Comment: Are those warnings shown during the compilation of the .xib file? If it’s public, could you post it somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot post them due to confidentiality. The errors show up permanently in the Issue Navigator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

Apparently XCode gets confused - at least that's my interpretation.

The warnings will disappear when you navigate to the Issue Navigator, right click the warning and choose "Open As - Source Code". You will then see an XML representation of your XIB. In my case I found some references to transitions but after closing them, they disappeared as did the warning.

Comment: That's too bad. it did for me.

Comment: @VibhorGoyal: Did you down vote my answer because it was not working for you?

Comment: Yes, and also because its not the correct answer. It is not just the xcode getting confused. There is something else thats causing it.

Comment: It is the correct answer as it solved MY problem. I can actually replicate the issue and solve it using the procedure described in my answer. The fact that it did not solve yours does not mean that your problem is the same as mine.

Answer (score 2):

Following thing worked for me, to get rid of this warning,

1 -- Open the XiB as a Source code, an XML file would open

2 -- Chop out following XML Section,

```
<!-- <object class="NSDictionary" key="NSViewAnimations">
                        <string key="NS.key.0">subviews</string>
                        <object class="CATransition" key="NS.object.0">
                            <object class="CIRippleTransition" key="filter">
                                <object class="NSCustomResource" key="CI_inputTargetImage">
                                    <string key="NSClassName">CIImage</string>
                                    <string key="NSResourceName">largegears</string>
                                </object>
                                <object class="NSCustomResource" key="CI_inputShadingImage">
                                    <string key="NSClassName">CIImage</string>
                                    <string key="NSResourceName">LogoLg</string>
                                </object>
                                <object class="CIVector" key="CI_inputCenter">
                                    <int key="CICount">2</int>
                                    <string key="CIVector">{{150, 150}, {0, 0}}</string>
                                </object>
                                <object class="CIVector" key="CI_inputExtent">
                                    <int key="CICount">4</int>
                                    <string key="CIVector">{{0, 0}, {300, 300}}</string>
                                </object>
                                <real value="0.0" key="CI_inputTime"/>
                                <real value="100" key="CI_inputWidth"/>
                                <real value="50" key="CI_inputScale"/>
                                <bool key="CIEnabled">YES</bool>
                            </object>
                            <string key="subtype">fromTop</string>
                            <string key="type">fade</string>
                            <object class="NSArray" key="__CACodingContents">
                                <bool key="EncodedWithXMLCoder">YES</bool>
                                <string>filter</string>
                                <string>subtype</string>
                                <string>type</string>
                            </object>
                        </object>
                    </object> -->
```

The Key is Search for CATransition and Commentout its corresponding NSDictionary attribute should comment out,

But ultimately , how its getting added has to be find out.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get rid of this warnings open the top in View's and see **View Effects Inspector** and check the view.

[image]

Comment: Worked for me in XCode 8.0 with my Mac OS project.

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at your top hierarchy of your view.
After I had played with some transitions within this hierarchy I also had this problem.

After some closer inspection I noticed that was still a filter active on the top hierarchy of the view in the core Animation Layer of IB. After removing that one, I was able to compile without the warning.